# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous Yii2

Tags: yii2

Helo, could someone explain me why I'm getting this error? What I was doing is that I'm trying to filter my `GridView` according to the `id's`, but it displays this error message. I've tried to search related information, but couldn't find what would be useful.

Here is my `Search` function:

```
    public function search($params)
{
    $query = Sale::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $query->joinWith('item');
    $dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'customer_name',
            'customer_surname',
            'customer_phone',
            'customer_email',
            'code',
            'comment',
            'sign',
            'price' => [
                'asc' =>['item.price' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' =>['item.price' => SORT_DESC],
            ],
            'item_id' => [
                'asc' =>['item.name' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' =>['item.name' => SORT_DESC],
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_name', $this->customer_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'item.name', $this->item_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like','sign', $this->sign])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_surname', $this->customer_surname])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_phone', $this->customer_phone])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer_email', $this->customer_email])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'code', $this->code])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'comment', $this->comment]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

It should work, because `id` has been added to `setSort()` and `filter` statements... Thank you for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should'nt work, cause u join `item` table, which propably have another `id` column. Change this:

```
// grid filtering conditions
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'id' => $this->id,
]);
```

to:

```
// grid filtering conditions
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'sale.id' => $this->id,
]);
```

Another way is to use aliases for tables.

Comment: It's more difficult to achieve it using aliases, particularly where using complex GridView links etc. The above is the neatest way.